# Does Kernel::srand have a maximum input value?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to seed a random number generator with the output of a hash. Currently I'm computing a SHA-1 hash, converting it to a giant integer, and feeding it to srand to initialize the RNG. This is so that I can get a predictable set of random numbers for an set of infinite cartesian coordinates (I'm hashing the coordinates).

I'm wondering whether Kernel::srand actually has a maximum value that it'll take, after which it truncates it in some way. The docs don't really make this obvious - they just say "a number".

I'll try to figure it out myself, but I'm assuming somebody out there has run into this already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing what programmers are like, it probably just calls libc's `srand()`. Either way, it's probably limited to 2^32-1, 2^31-1, 2^16-1, or 2^15-1.

There's also a danger that the value is clipped when cast from a biginteger to a C int/long, instead of only taking the low-order bits.

An easy test is to seed with 1 and take the first output. Then, seed with 2<sup>i</sup>+1 for `i` in [1..64] or so, take the first output of each, and compare. If you get a match for some `i=n` and all greater `i`s, then it's probably doing arithmetic modulo 2<sup>n</sup>.

Note that the random number generator is almost certainly limited to 32 or 48 bits of entropy anyway, so there's little point seeding it with a huge value, and an attacker can reasonably easily predict future outputs given past outputs (and an "attacker" could simply be a player on a public nethack server).

**EDIT:** So I was wrong.

According to the docs for Kernel::rand(),

> Ruby currently uses a modified Mersenne Twister with a period of 2**19937-1.

This means it's not just a call to libc's `rand()`. The Mersenne Twister is statistically superior (but not cryptographically secure). But anyway.

Testing using `Kernel::srand(0); Kernel::sprintf("%x",Kernel::rand(2**32))` for various output sizes (2**16, 2**32, 2**36, 2**60, 2**64, 2**32+1, 2**35, 2**34+1), a few things are evident:

1. It figures out how many bits it needs (number of bits in `max-1`).
2. It generates output in groups of 32 bits, most-significant-bits-first, and drops the top bits (i.e. 0x[r0][r1][r2][r3][r4] with the top bits masked off).
3. If it's not less than `max`, it does some sort of retry. It's not obvious what this is from the output.
4. If it is less than `max`, it outputs the result.

I'm not sure why 2**32+1 and 2**64+1 are special (they produce the same output from `Kernel::rand(2**1024)` so probably have the exact same state) — I haven't found another collision.

The good news is that it doesn't simply clip to some arbitrary maximum (i.e. passing in huge numbers isn't equivalent to passing in 2**31-1), which is the most obvious thing that can go wrong. Kernel::srand() also returns the previous seed, which appears to be 128-bit, so it seems likely to be safe to pass in something large.

**EDIT 2:** Of course, there's no guarantee that the output will be reproducible between different Ruby versions (the docs merely say what it "currently uses"; apparently this was initially committed in 2002). Java has several portable deterministic PRNGs (`SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG","SUN")`, albeit slow); I'm not aware of something similar for Ruby.

Comment: I tried your method, and it looks like the result of seeding with `2**32 + 1` is the same as `2**64 + 1` but not 1. Not too sure what that means.

Comment: A more immediately useful question might be: what's the best way to chop up the output of SHA-1 so that it's a decent input for srand (lets say 32 bits). Can I just take the bottom 4 bytes of the output?

Comment: @robbles: Edited. It appears safe to just pass in a 160-bit integer.